# Is the usage of the tense here correct?

Tags: tense

> I’m so tired of Sophie **showing** off her engagement ring all the time.
>
> Isha enjoyed her time as she watched her husband **play** the gentleman.

The latter should be 'playing'?The first is just for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the perception verbs (*see*, *watch*, *hear*, *observe*, &c) take clauses headed by either an *-ing* form or an unmarked infinitive as complements.

> She watched her husband play the cello.
>   She watched her husband playing the cello.

When the complement clause is headed by an "atelic" verb—a verb which doesn't imply reaching a goal or a final change of state—there's no real difference between the infinitival and the *-ing* form versions. To *play* + instrument is an activity which has no definite end, so the two sentences above have pretty much the same meaning.

But if the complement clause is headed by a "telic" verb—one which does imply a goal or end—there is a difference.

> She watched her husband play the Walton Cello Concerto.
>   She watched her husband playing the Walton Cello Concerto.

To *play* a particular work is a telic expression, because the work has a definite end; you play the work all the way through. Here using the infinitival implies that she watched her husband play the concerto all the way to the end, while using the *-ing* form implies only that she watched her husband for some time while he was playing; she may have left before he finished, or something may have interrupted his playing.

Comment: Reading the difference in meanings part reminded me of verbs like **love, hate, like...** which take either a gerund or a to infinitive. I read somewhere generally there is no difference in meaning. But this is my inference: in some situations there is a difference. Imagine when two friends are walking on a beach, if one of them says:"I love swimming." it means s/he is merely informing the friend about it. But if s/he says "I love to swim." the persong is telling that s/he wants to swim at the moment. Am I right?

Comment: @Sina No, both are merely informative.

Comment: Parden me for taking your time.If you feel it is inconvenient, just let me know to stop it. Then I pist it as a question and there would be no more bother, I promise:) I googled the question and it maked me truely confused. Some natives told if you speak generally whether you do an activity or not, you should use gerund form. But for special situations to infinitive, like you do something as a habit. Others wrote, if you do something use the gerund to state you enjoy doing it. If you don't do an activity use infinitive to talk about potentiality of it.

Comment: And one had posted gerund is general, infinitive means you want to do sth!%-( which one is correct?!

Comment: @Sima I'm afraid there's no consistent rule: it varies from context to context and verb to verb. Gerund complements have been gradually replacing infinitivals for a couple of centuries now, but even in the face of this "Great Complement Shift" some verbs have gone in the opposite direction.

Comment: I'm tremendously thankful you answerd my question. Sorry for taking your precious time:-)